# How are Thunderbird sender/"from" icons set?

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird shows icons next to the senders address. Maybe I've just not noticed it before, but I'm pretty sure it is new. Where are those icons provided from (i.e., how do I make it show up for my domains)? It does not seem to be favicon from the domain. Here's examples from eBay and PayPal:

[image: ebay icon in Thunderbird]

[image]

(I haven't disabled all my extensions to verify that it is based T-bird, but I don't think any of the extensions would do this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just wondered the same thing, and in my case, it seems to be the extension 'DKIM Verifier'.

Comment: This seems to be more of a clue/guess than a definitive answer. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Correct! I should have checked those add-ons. Added in 1.6.0. Sounds like it is only for certain hardcoded domains. https://github.com/lieser/dkim_verifier/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt

Comment: :). It would make a great TB feature, potentially...

Comment: Soo, is it possible to add your own icon?

Comment: @Orphans Actually with BIMI this might become a more widely supported feature. But it does require paying for a specific certificate

Comment: @Avamander Yes, VMC (Verified Mark Certificate).